# In Rails 3 data save with out p()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In the below code retrive data from database arrange those & delete from database again insert

```
page_nos = [10,11,12,13,14,20,21,22,23,24,30,31,32,33,34,40,41,42,43,44]

page_nos.each do |page|
  @page_data = HomePageSetting.where("page_no = '#{page}'").order("score desc")
  p(@page_data)
  HomePageSetting.where("page_no = #{page}").delete_all
  @page_data.each do |data|
    @home_page = HomePageSetting.new
    @home_page.subject_id = data.subject_id
        @home_page.subject_type = data.subject_type
        @home_page.score = data.score
        @home_page.flag = data.flag
        @home_page.flag_detail = data.flag_detail
        @home_page.page_no = data.page_no
        @home_page.release_date = data.release_date
        @home_page.item_created_at = data.item_created_at
        @home_page.save
      end
    end
```

that is not working if i remove p(@page_data) line

Comment: Why are you deleting and reinserting the same records?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but I suspect I do know the reason that outputting the `@page_data` variable makes a difference.

`@page_data` is an ActiveRecord::Relation object - that is, a stored SQL query. Because executing a query and loading the resulting objects into memory takes time, Rails doesn't actually execute the query until it has to. When you output `@page_data`, its has to instantiate those objects to print the output. They then exist in memory, and can be referenced even after you delete their rows from the database in the next line.

If you *don't* print out that data, it stays uninstantiated on the next line, where you delete all those rows. Then, you call `.each` on it, and it gets instantiated *at that point*, and there are no objects to fetch, because you just deleted them all.

You can force Rails to instantiate the relation when you first define `@page_data` by calling `.all`, on it, thus:

```
@page_data = HomePageSetting.where("page_no = '#{page}'").order("score desc").all
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if one problem at least is that you're calling `.save` inside the `.new` block -- you should save the record *after*.

Here's the changed code:

```
page_nos = [10,11,12,13,14,20,21,22,23,24,30,31,32,33,34,40,41,42,43,44]

page_nos.each do |page|
  @page_data = HomePageSetting.where("page_no = '#{page}'").order("score desc")
  p(@page_data)
  HomePageSetting.where("page_no = #{page}").delete_all
  @page_data.each do |data|
    @home_page = HomePageSetting.new
    @home_page.subject_id = data.subject_id
        @home_page.subject_type = data.subject_type
        @home_page.score = data.score
        @home_page.flag = data.flag
        @home_page.flag_detail = data.flag_detail
        @home_page.page_no = data.page_no
        @home_page.release_date = data.release_date
        @home_page.item_created_at = data.item_created_at
      end
      @home_page.save
    end
```

When I'm having problems like this I also sometimes will use `.save!` -- it will halt processing and throw an exception if the data doesn't save correctly. `.save` can fail silently and simply return `false`. To try that use `@home_page.save!` instead.

Good luck!